# Create a matrix of vectors with different length in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix, vector

I have a dataset with data in which at each time a value from a given user is achieved. I would like to create a dataframe for each user ID or a matrix of vectors where I can add a value independently. For instance:

```
      t0 t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 ... tM 
User1 2  3
User2 3  5  7 
User3 1  2  3  5
..
UserN 1
```

The idea is being able to access each User data as a vector and add a new value if needed. I don't know if a matrix of vectors is the most efficient way or a dict. Another idea could be to create dataframes with names in a For loop.

How can I do it?

Comment: `dictionary` perhaps.

Comment: any idea how to start with?